# Sql connection error through binding source database connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, database-connection

This is my code for connection:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class frm_edit_patient
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Private Sub frm_edit_patient_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        frm_dashboard.Enabled = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frm_edit_patient_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet1.patients' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PatientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.patients)
        frm_dashboard.Enabled = False
        Try
            Dim myConString As String = My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString
            con.ConnectionString = myConString
            con.Open()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        frm_dashboard.Enabled = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

but this is giving me error:

[image]

I am using binding source for database connection....

Comment: What do you mean: *I am using binding source for database connection*?  That does not make sense...

Comment: The error is quite clear: *The server was not found or was not accessible*

Comment: Does `My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString` contain the correct connection string? Is that SQL Server running?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Like i have displayed database items using dataGridView and BindingSource as given in one of the tutorial. Now i want to fetch the data manually for my textboxes. So i used `My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString` and got this error. If you can help, please... i am learning.

Comment: On which line you get the exception?

Comment: On which line is the exception *thrown* the 19th line is where it is *caught*

Comment: @MattWilko I think it would be on this line `con.Open()`

Comment: @MattWilko It's obvious `con.Open()`

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - Obviously not to @ Steve !

Comment: Come on guys, the error is totally clear here. Golden Heat: Just make sure the Sql Server is up and `My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString` contains the correct connection string.

Comment: Counting on your code, line 19 is on the MessageBox call. Well looking at the exception trace is line 15. The Open statement. So put a breakpoint on that line (15) and when hit check if the database specified on Database1ConnectionString  really exist.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus `My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString` contains `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database.sdf is a Sql Compact database file, not a Sql Server catalog name.

You need to use [`SqlCeConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) not a `SqlConnection`

Thus you need to declare

```
Dim con As New SqlCeConnection
```

also remember that you need a reference to the assembly System.Data.SqlServerCe
(in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll)